# How to get the distance of multiple location in array from one location and Sort that array by nearest distance in iOS?

Tags: ios

I am working on a project in which I have to show the distance of multiple locations from one location. locations are based on latitude and longitude.

I am using the following code to get the distance between two locations is shows nearly same distance

```
CLLocation *locationA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:28.6379 longitude: 77.2432];CLLocation *locationB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:28.6562 longitude:77.2410];CLLocationDistance distance = [locationA distanceFromLocation:locationB];NSLog(@"Distance is %f",distance);float i  = distance/1000;NSLog(@"distance between two places is %f KM", i);
```

but now i am struct to get the distance of multiple locations from my location: locationA.

for example I take NSArray for latitude and longitude as

```
NSArray * latitudeArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"28.6129",@"28.6020",@"28.5244", nil];NSArray * longitudeArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"77.2295",@"77.2478",@"77.1855", nil];
```

Please help me to resolve it..

Take locationA as one location..

Please help me to sort the Array by nearest Distance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't create two array for latitude and longitude, It should be one array of CLLocations.

```
  NSMutableArray locationsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //This is just for example, You should add locations to this array according to format of data you have available.

    [locationsArray addObject:[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:28.6379 longitude:77.2432]];
    [locationsArray addObject:[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:28.6020 longitude:77.2478]];
    [locationsArray addObject:[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:28.5244 longitude:77.1855]];
```

Now, Take some reference location,

```
CLLocation *yourLocationA ; //set whatever value you have..
```

You can sort array of location with following.

```
 [locationsArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(CLLocation *obj1Location,CLLocation *obj2Location) {
            CLLocationDistance obj1Distance = [obj1Location distanceFromLocation: yourLocationA];
            CLLocationDistance obj2Distance = [obj2Location distanceFromLocation: yourLocationA];

            return (obj1Distance > obj2Distance);

    }];
```

Comment: Thanks for answer@iOS_developer